# Perl: eval an unpacked hex value passed through any level of ssh

Tags: code-golf, perl

### Task

Make code given on the command line that takes an unpacked hex value as input and `eval`s that in Perl. Like this:

```
perl -e 'map{eval}pack q/h*/,q/072796e6470222458656275672370202d6f62756020222b302072796e6470222478616e60202f6e6560202771697020247f6020246f602029647e2c5e622/'
```

But with one additional restriction: Your code must survive any level of `ssh`

(and the example above does not survive because the space would need to be quoted:

```
# This does not work
ssh server perl -e 'map{eval}pack q/h*/,q/072796e6470222458656275672370202d6f62756020222b302072796e6470222478616e60202f6e6560202771697020247f6020246f602029647e2c5e622/'
# This would survive 1 level of ssh but not 2
ssh server perl -e 'map{eval}pack\ q/h*/,q/072796e6470222458656275672370202d6f62756020222b302072796e6470222478616e60202f6e6560202771697020247f6020246f602029647e2c5e622/'
```

)

So:

```
ssh server your_code hexvalue
ssh server ssh server2 your_code hexvalue
ssh server ssh server2 ssh server3 your_code hexvalue
```

should all give the same result. You will not be told the number of levels of `ssh`.

You can assume the login shell is bash.

You can choose to include the hex value in the program (in which case it obviously does not count towards the length of your code) or have it given as an argument to your program.

You are also allowed to preprocess the hex value (e.g. convert it to another format) and use that value instead. But you cannot do the `eval` locally: It must be run on the remote server. The preprocessing code is of course also code thus also part of the byte count.

### Test

Given the value:

```
072796e6470222458656275672370202d6f62756020222b302072796e6470222478616e60202f6e6560202771697020247f6020246f602029647e2c5e622
```

your program should print:

```
There's  more  than  one  way  to  do  it.
```

And:

```
4216d3223616d656c622b302072796e6470222140242160296e6024786560246563737562747e2c5e622
```

should print:

```
A camel in the dessert.
```

Finally:

```
072796e647020686f63747e616d65606
```

should print the hostname of the server that you `ssh` to.

### Scoring

Code that only uses Perl wins over code that uses Bash+Perl which wins over code in any other languages.

In case of a tie: Code without warnings wins.

In case of a tie: Shortest code wins.

*Edit*

Clarified preprocessing is allowed, but not for free, and warnings are frowned upon, but not illegal.

Comment: Given the rule that allows you to preprocess the value before inserting it into the program, how is such a program to be scored? If the preprocessed value isn’t included in the byte count, nothing would stop you from asserting that the *entire program* is part of the preprocessed value (for example, you might assert that the `eval+v` in [ais523’s answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/241612/39242) is just as much a part of the preprocessed format as the `.`s), leading to a score of 0 bytes.

Comment: @AndersKaseorg Clarified that preprocessing is not for free.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Perl only; (+0 bytes) 23 bytes

Saved two bytes thanks to [Ole Tange](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/25339/ole-tange) themself! (`'+'` -> `+`)

```
map{eval}pack+q/h*/,q/$hexvalue/
```

Disclaimer: I have no experience with Perl whatsoever.
However, this seems to work fine, I simply replaced the single space in the example with `'+'`, which has now been golfed to just `+`.

For example:

```
ssh localhost ssh localhost [...] ssh localhost perl -e 'map{eval}pack'+'q/h*/,q/072796e647020686f63747e616d65606/'
```

(We can't seem to ssh even to `localhost` over on [TIO](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/vyC1KEdBN1VBPTexoDq1LDGntiAxOVu7UD9DS1@nUN/A3Mjc0izVzMTcwMjAzMIszczY3MQ81czQLMXM1MzATF@dq7g4QyEnPzkxJyO/uEQBxKOFmQgexab//w8A) though)

Comment: @OleTange - does this conform to your specification? I notice that your examples are `ssh server ssh server2 ... ssh serverN your_code hexvalue` which this one does not fit with (i.e. the hex value is in the code much like your first example).

Comment: Yes, that is OK: "You can choose to include the hex value in the program".

Comment: "no experience with Perl whatsoever" - seems like you know more than the basics. I cant even understand what your code means but okey 1+ for the bytes

Comment: @DialFrost Nope, I've never used Perl before; I really just tried it, thinking it might work :)

Comment: You can remove the ' s, too.

Comment: @OleTange Ha ha, wonderful!

Comment: `map{eval}` can just be `eval+`

Comment: @Sisyphus not sure if we're allowed to produce a warning along with the output.

Comment: @JonathanAllan The rules were unclear on warnings. I have made them clear: Warnings are allowed, but frowned upon.

Answer (score 0):

## Pure [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 6 bytes + 8 bytes for a change to the preprocessing format = 14 bytes

```perl
eval+v
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z@1LDFHu8zQ0EjP0NBEz9DAFEgbALGZnrGRnqmBngmI/P8fAA)

This is followed by the code that you want to evaluate written with codepoints in decimal and separated by periods, e.g.

```perl
perl -e eval+v112.114.105.110.116.32.50.42.50
```

Produces a warning about ambiguous syntax (the `+` could be interpreted as either unary + (a no-op) or as addition), but the parse that Perl chooses by default works.

### Encoders

The format listed in the question is *not* the usual hex encoding; the first example starts with `07`, which in a normal hexdump, would represent the BEL character. I suspect it has been produced using code that's something like this:

```perl
print unpack("h*", "print 2*2")
```

(A "regular" hexdump would use the `H*` unpack format, rather than `h*`.)

To produce the format used by this answer, you unpack with `c*` rather than `h*`, and with `$,` set to `"."`:

```perl
$,=".";print unpack("C*", "print 2*2")
```

Encoding it using Perl therefore takes 8 more bytes than encoding the format stated in the question.

Alternatively, you can use [this online encoder](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/98/61HDXL1HDXNSyxJztMuAHOv///8XFGXmlSgYaRkBAA), written in Jelly.

### Explanation

```perl
eval+vn.n.n.n.n.n…
eval                 Evaluates a string literal as code
    +                No-op (used here as a whitespace substitute)
     vn.n.n.n.n.n…   String literal specified using character codes
```

All the characters in this program are invariant under shell escaping (it's just letters, digits, `+` and `.`), so it can be passed through any number of shell command lines and will remain intact.

Comment: I don’t see any justification in the question for subtracting the byte count of the suspected code for encoding the format stated in the question.

Comment: The question uses a nonstandard format (and hasn't documented it) – thus, preprocessing it into any other format involves undoing the nonstandard format first to get back to the original string. In practice, you're unlikely to generate strings in that format except via using Perl `unpack`, and so if you wanted to solve this sort of problem practically, you'd modify your existing encoder rather than using the existing encoder, reversing the encoding to get back at the original string, and redoing the encoding with slightly different settings.

Comment: Then ask the question author whether the scoring should be changed. You can’t just make up your own scoring.

Comment: Or to put it another way – the question would have made more sense if it had asked for an encoder that started with the original string, rather than an encoder that starts with the string in `unpack 'h*'` format, because you generally only find a string in `unpack 'h*'` format if you created it yourself with `unpack 'h*'`. (I interpreted the question as an attempt to solve a practical problem, so I'm providing a practical solution – there's an XY issue in the original question and this answer is pointing it out.)

Comment: A different question might have made more sense. It would, however, be a different question. You need to ask the question author if they want to change it.

Comment: I can't – I don't have enough rep. (The question has also already been changed once since I posted this answer – it was a correct answer at the time it was posted, and it gets quite time-consuming to keep up with the changes.)

Comment: It looks like you’ve been marking all your answers as community wiki; that’s why you aren’t gaining any rep.